# How do I update a single row in each group?

Tags: r, data.table

I've got data big enough to need `data.table` for the first time ever, and I've been very pleased with how easy it's been so far. I've read quite a bit of documentation today (certainly not nearly all of it), but I haven't found this yet.

I've got a data table keyed by `placeid` and `t2`, with one other column, `t1`. What I'd like to do is set `t1` to `0` in each row where `t2` is at its minimum, by `placeid`.

```
## Sample data
set.seed(47)
require(data.table)
dt <- data.table(placeid = rep(letters[1:3], each = 3), t1 = runif(9), t2 = runif(9))
setkeyv(dt, cols=c("placeid", "t2"))
```

As `t2` is in the key, the row I want to change is the first one within each grouping. I was able to get it to work with an `ifelse` statement, but **is there a better way to do it using the `i` argument of `[.data.table`?**

I was hoping one of these would work, though on thinking tiny bit more it makes sense that they don't:

```
dt[1, t1 := 0, by = placeid] ## changes only first row
dt[which.min(t2), t1 := 0, by = placeid] ## changes only global min row
```

What I did find to work (the result being the desired output):

```
dt[, t1 := ifelse(t2 == min(t2), 0, t1), by = placeid]  # works
```

Comment: Here's another possibility: `dt[,t1:=t1*(t2!=min(t2)),by='placeid']`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you know that `dt` is keyed (ie sorted) by `placeid` and `t2`, then the first row by `placeid` is the row you wish to update.

You can use `mult = 'first'` to match the first row only when joining on the unique values of `placeid`

```
dt[unique(placeid),t1 := 0,mult='first']
dt
#    placeid        t1         t2
# 1:       a 0.0000000 0.13879758
# 2:       a 0.7615020 0.70198720
# 3:       a 0.9769620 0.92489205
# 4:       b 0.0000000 0.16219364
# 5:       b 0.6914124 0.50603611
# 6:       b 0.5735444 0.59930702
# 7:       c 0.0000000 0.03094497
# 8:       c 0.4689460 0.40050280
# 9:       c 0.3890619 0.90197352
```

If there is the possibility that you wish to update more than one row in the case where there are multiple rows where t2 == min(t2), you can use `.I[t2==min(t2)]` to identify these rows by `placeid`

```
dt[dt[,.I[t2 == min(t2)],by='placeid']$V1, t1 := 0]
```

Note that this will be slower as than the binary search option above.